# Test facebook sdk for android on multiple devices

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the facebook sdk for android for developing an application.I generated the hash key as suggested in the official tutorial and then tested the samples on my emulator and my phone. Seems to be working fine. But when I run the samples from eclipse on a different device, the login fails. I need to test the login functionality on different devices.

I also tried creating another developer account and adding my androiddebug hash key to its setting, but even that doesn't work.

How do I manage to test and debug the login samples on multiple phones?

Comment: Have you set your Sandbox Mode option Disabled in Basic info ?

Comment: Go to your app and select Edit option from right corner. And in Basic info just disable Sandbox Mode and Save Changes...I guess it will work fine on other devices also...